# Why is there a doubled name in the Photos app when I search to name faces?

Tags: macos, photos.app

The image below represents what I mean: Even though there is only one **Bartłomiej Semańczyk** in my Contacts, that person appears on the list below twice.

**How do I remove repeated options on the list when I search to name faces?**

[image]

Comment: did you import the library from iPhoto?

Comment: yes, I imported them from iPhoto

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One is the original name tag you supplied in iPhoto, the other is the closest possible Contact in your Address Book.

I went through the same process yesterday - trying to decide whether I wanted people tagged as names, or Contacts.

<strike>I can find no way to switch it off - nor, even more irritatingly, how to assign all photos with a particular face to the Contact instead of the original name, other than one at a time…</strike>

*Edit:*
Simpler than I first thought - Select one 'Face' in the main faces screen, click the name & start to type. Choose whether to use the Original tag name or the new Contact name. All similarly-tagged faces will be changed to the new system & the old tag will vanish.

I made a silly one as an example…

- a. Start to type, you have 2 alternatives, select the Contact name
- b. Hit Enter, the Contact Name is embedded
- c. Try to repeat the process… there is now only one choice for that person [or cat]

[image]

There's a huge, detailed Photos guide on [iMore - How to use Photos for OS X: The ultimate guide](http://www.imore.com/how-use-photos-os-x-ultimate-guide)

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk - I updated my answer with an actual working solution.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. When I type second time, I have also 2 possibilities...

Comment: Are you doing it from the 'global' faces screen, or from an individual photo? I first tried with one photo, but that just generated 2 different 'faces' one with each info & the double still remained. It will, of course, never get rid of the Contacts version if you tag it with the 'handwritten' version. You must switch to the contacts version to lose the old one.

Comment: I added another comment, as you were sending, see above

Comment: It doesn't disappear because, the contact's name and label's name are THE SAME. Your solution works only if label and contacts ARE NOT the same:)

Comment: I just tested on other, real contacts & the old tag merges in, even if the names were identical beforehand

Comment: If I had the same tag in iPhoto, and now in Photos I have the same contact, then I have to change the contact name, then assign that changed contact to the face (global), then change contact to correct name, and finally assign correct contact name to the global face. Now if you type once again, you see ONLY ONE label - your current label from contacts

Answer (score 2):

It happens because iPhoto, when facial recognising was born, doesn't support contact integration so, when you recognise faces you link them to "handwrite" labels, not a contact.

Later, iPhoto was updated to support contact integration so, after this update, you can keep linking faces to handwrite labels or start linking them to contact labels. But iPhoto isn't able to merge handwrite whith contact labels and it generate confusion because, in lot of libraries, start born lot of faces with double labels.

To correct this issue you can merge manually all handwrite labels with contact labels. To do that:

- go into Photos faces screen.
- find faces which has two label for the same person (for example, in your faces screen, you have two labels for Bartłomiej Semańczyk probably strewn between all your faces; one with, as picture in the circle, his faces rotated 90° (which is the handwrite label) and one while he's swimming (which is the contact label) ).
- select one of the two labels for that face, I suggest the handwrite label (in your case the one with rotated picture), and click on the name label to rename it, start typing the name then, when appear the suggestion list, select the other label for that person (in your case the one while he's swimming).

Photos (or iPhoto, is the same) will merge that faces into the same person.

Comment: How do you 'link them to the same label' ?

Comment: Edited answer with more detailed "tutorial"

Comment: Trying this on myself - I open 1 pic with my face, listed as first name only. There is no double label until I clear the name & start to type. After that I choose my contact instead of original name. I now have 1 photo tagged as 'my contact' & 500 still as 'first name' I see no way to make this automatic.

Comment: Ah, OK, I got it - rename the 'global' name in Faces, not in any one picture.

Comment: You've to rename the "master label" on the general faces screen, where you see all the faces in your library... actually I can't find a better way to explain it...it's easier to do than explain!! =)

Comment: I tweaked my own answer & added a pictorial explanation - easy once I grasped it, ty.