# Can I assign my named faces in Photos app to Contacts?

Tags: automator, photos.app, contacts.app

I want use the faces which I determined in Photos app and named them. I have contacts with the same names. I want to link these and I would it done automatically.
Is there any way to do this?

**EDIT :** I saw the links which @Tetsujin introduced me, but I can't solve my problem. In addition, I use Persian names which can make some differences.

Comment: see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/215674/contact-picture-not-connect-with-faces-on-photo/215694#215694 & also http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/182615/why-is-there-a-doubled-name-in-the-photos-app-when-i-search-to-name-faces/182616#182616 which was kind of halfway through figuring it all out

Comment: @Tetsujin I just have Photos app. I don't have iPhoto. Doesn't it make any changes in my position.

Comment: No difference in that respect, in fact my first link was done on Photos in El Capitan, the 2nd, older link on iPhoto in Yosemite.